# Jquery: Trying to combine Click, animate, fadeout, and location

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, location, fadeout

I am trying to figure out how to modify this script to add new functions.

1. Once the a.fromwork link is clicked, the div.dash should fadeout to the left.
2. The div#titleMove starts its fadeout and its animate to left.
3. Location then takes over and you move to the next page.

I have tried a number of things to do this. I need your help, any ideas?

```
<ul class="crumbs">
    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/work/" class="fromwork">&larr; Work</a></li>
    <li class="dash">&mdash;</li>
    <li><div id="titleMove"><?php the_title(); ?></div></li>
</ul>


// Fade Script
$('.fromwork').click(function(){
  var href= $(this).attr('href');

  // do animation

  $('#titleMove').fadeOut( 200, function(){
        // go to link when animation completes
        window.location=href;

  })
  $('body').fadeOut(1000);
  // over ride browser following link when clicked
  return false;
})
```

Comment: Looks like you might need to do `event.preventDefault()` as well

Answer (score 0):

Use `.delay()` and `.animate()` using a negative `margin-left`. Or make sure the parent of `li.dash` is `position:relative;`, then `position:absolute` `li.dash` and use negative `left`.